# Migration from Distributed File System 2003 to 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, replication, dfs

I have two Windows Server 2003 and both have DFS and it does replication between them.

I would like to migrate the primary win2k3 DFS server to win2k8. what is the best way to do that?

I found this article:
Migrate a Domain-based Namespace to Windows Server 2008 Mode
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753875.aspx

But I am interested only on migrating the DFS replication and not the namespace.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand.. You're asking how you can upgrade your operating system?

Comment: no, I already have another windows server 2008 and want to move Distributed file system from server 2003 to server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

(Follow up from the comments)

You say that you already have a new 2008 server that you want to use, so this is trivial. Wether or not you choose to keep the old 2003 server running has no impact.

Just add the 2008 server as a DFS member and set up replication.

Comment: Ok, there is also namespaces in the main win2k3:                     "\\domain_name\public"  how do I transfer it to the win2k8 server?     thanks a bunch

Comment: You don't transfer it, the namespace is in AD. You just add/remove members. Edit: To clarify, you add/remove namespace servers

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question you are asking is how to migrate from FRS to DFS-R.

This article ["Migrating from FRS to DFS-R"](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/r2/archive/2006/01/05/380.aspx) seems to cover the details.

If you are just asking how you would use a 2008 server in a replication setup with 2003 systems, then you just add it through the MMC.  You can only convert to the new replication method after you have upgraded everything to 2003 R2 or above.